# How to add a class to an element based on another elements left value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you visit this [code pen](http://codepen.io/Magicrecon/pen/BRzXRa) and click anywhere on the home page it cycles through three boxes. If you scroll down you will see the content changes too.

I want to underline the correct nav bar word depending on the box currently being displayed.

Box 2 is the default at page load, and then the nav-bar should have the underline class active on the `id="home"`. Then you click and it moves to box 3, which should apply the underline class to `id="blog"`.

It is using left values to cycle through the elements. How can I check which box is active just by looking at the *left* value?

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) 
        {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } 
        else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) 
        {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '0%',
            }, 500 );
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500 );
        }
    });
});
```

The class I want to apply

```
.underline-active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

to the corresponding nav-bar ID:

```
#box1 {
    left: -150%;
}

#box2 {
}

#box3 {
    left: 150%;
}
```

Also, is there a way to animate the underline sliding from one nav item to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navbar elements might be a little too big since whenever I add the `.underline-active` class to the them it extends past the edge of the element (at the same time, this would probably make creating a css animation easier since they seem to be equidistant this way).

In any event, you can do this with another `$().each()` call. Just look for whichever element has `offset.left == 0`. JQuery provides plenty of methods to add/remove CSS classes to an item so from there it's simply figuring out which navbar element gets the `.underline-active` class which I did using a switch statement. Your new js should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#home').addClass('underline-active');
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) 
        {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } 
        else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) 
        {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '0%',
            }, 500 );
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500 );
        }
    });
    $('.nav-button').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('underline-active');
    });
    $(".box").each(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().left == 0) {
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
          case 'box1': 
            $('#home').addClass('underline-active'); 
            break;
          case 'box2':
            $('#blog').addClass('underline-active'); 
            break;
          case 'box3':
            $('#about').addClass('underline-active'); 
            break;
       }
      }
    })
  });  
});
```

If you want to animate the movement of the underline then you should alter this process slightly to use transitions instead of removing/adding it from elements. I'd imagine you can use the same animation that scrolls the page to move the underline since the navbar elements seem to be a consistent distance apart.

Comment: Brilliant, as soon as im home i'll test it and mark your answer accordingly, many thanks for taking the time to answer, will update you later.

Comment: So sorry for late response, i haven't forgot! Just tested and it does exactly what i asked for so big kudos man. Take care and thanks for the help.